# Remove files from remote repo only

Tags: git, github

I did kind of a bad thing on my branch, and now it's a bit messed up.

I am developing a magento extension, and I accidentally commited some core files, and some folders similar to `.idea` to github.

What I want to do now is to remove these files from git, and keep them on my local branch. I tried the following (but didn't work):

```
git rm -rf --cache .idea
git add -A
git commit -m "remove unnecessary files"
git push origin blog
```

But it had no effect.

PS: In the meantime, I did a lot of useful commits, so reverting would be ... unpleasant :)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `git add -A` command added back all files you unstaged. If you always checked the diff before committing you would notice this.

Comment: Ah yes, that was my problem it seems. It makes sense in retrospect, but I did the git add out of reflex :)

Answer (score 2):

removing the files seems to already have been answered here: [Completely remove files from Git repo and remote on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563564/remove-files-from-git-repo-completely)

to prevent those files from being uploaded again while keeping them locally push a different branch to git that doesn't contain your secret files. :)