# File keeps coming back

Tags: git, gitignore

We have set up our `.gitignore` file to ignore

- all files ending in `*.sdf`
- as well as the full path to the file, e.g. `/MyProject/Database/MyDatabase.sdf` with `/` being the project's root (top-level directory checked into git) to specifically ignore that one file

but the file keeps coming back as it is checked in by various members of the team.

Any ideas how to **really** exclude the `.sdf` file for good?

We can't quite grasp why it keeps popping up in the modified files for everybody..

Answer (score 5):

If it pop in the `modified files` it probably means you have already committed the file by the past. Before adding the `.gitignore` rule.

Am I right?

You will have to remove it via `git rm` and commit the change.

Comment: We keep deleting the file (via git) - and still it keeps popping up as modified

Comment: modified or untracked?

Comment: we're not entirely sure - somebody in the team keeps committing it accidentally, when we notice it's back again it's hard to track. But we're 90% sure it keeps showing up as modified - otherwise you wouldn't commit it w/o consciously adding it to source control, right?

Comment: Yeah. It's a tricky one. Once the file is tracked by Git, you have to make it forget it has ever existed. At some point you will have to make all your developers up to date with that.

Comment: If you can't manage to have everyone up to date with the "delete" part (either you work on branches or whatever) you might want to actually remove the file from the history, for real (Like killing hitler). Please look at this post as it explains the right usage of git filter-branch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563564/completely-remove-files-from-git-repo-and-remote-on-github

Comment: But keep in mind that is a drastic process and you will have to push --force the history and it won't be pretty when other devs would want to sync their own work. I strongly suggest you to talk to the other devs to make sure the file is delete

Comment: Often `git rm --cached` is better than simply `git rm`, as it will leave the file in your working directory but delete it from Git.