# How to remove Intellij files from git completly

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I was commiting intellij files in git but that was a mistake. How to clean them from entire git history?

this is something I should add to git ignore

```
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm

## Directory-based project format
.idea/
/*.iml
# if you remove the above rule, at least ignore user-specific stuff:
# .idea/workspace.xml
# .idea/tasks.xml
# .idea/dictionaries
# and these sensitive or high-churn files:
# .idea/dataSources.ids
# .idea/dataSources.xml
# .idea/sqlDataSources.xml
# .idea/dynamic.xml
# and, if using gradle::
# .idea/gradle.xml
# .idea/libraries

## File-based project format
*.ipr
*.iws

## Additional for IntelliJ
out/

# generated by mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# generated by JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# generated by Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and Intellij)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completely remove files from Git repo and remote on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563564/completely-remove-files-from-git-repo-and-remote-on-github)

Comment: those answers are just for one file, not for entire folder or all extensions like *iml. any idea how to do that?

Comment: Git doesn't manage folders. You have to remove all files you want to get rid of.