# Git: Remove files from history which named like a CLI option

Tags: git

I accidentally added a huge file to my repo (~250 MB) with the name `--exclude`. This file was generated on OS X while I was writing some new code for this repo. Now, I was trying to learn how to delete it from Git's history from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563564/completely-remove-files-from-git-repo-and-remote-on-github) and [here](http://naleid.com/blog/2012/01/17/finding-and-purging-big-files-from-git-history). The tutorials are nice and clear, but the problem is that Git "thinks"  `--exclude`  is not a file but an option.

When I run this command:

```
git filter-branch \
    --index-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch '--exclude' " HEAD
```

Git complains:

```
error: unknown option `exclude'
usage: git rm [<options>] [--] <file>...
```

I tried to use file's sha number but it changed nothing.What is the correct way to delete such a files?

Comment: Can you try using wildcards? Not sure what git accepts but perhaps `*exclude` ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, you can. Nice idea! See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35681754/674064).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common UNIX way of constructing argument line is

```
<command> <keys&arguments> [--] <arguments>
```

In you case

```
command: git rm
keys: -r --cached --ignore-unmatch
arguments: '--exclude'
```

Usually keys are detected by leading `-`s.

But you can always force move them to arguments by explicitly writing them in the arguments part of the line using `--`
So you get

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch -- '--exclude' " HEAD
```

Comment: Note that what this answer calls 'keys' are also often called 'options' and that keys/options are arguments, too, so that what this answer calls 'arguments' are sometimes called 'non-option arguments'. Further note that (other than many other UNIX commands) with most (probably all) git subcommands, you can't put arbitrary non-option arguments after the `--` separator, but only files and directories.

Answer (score 3):

Try at least to separate the `git rm` *options* from the file parameters, using a '`--`' (double-hyphen)

```
 git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch -- '--exclude' " HEAD
                                                                       ^^
                                                                 (double-hyphen)
```

See more on the double hyphen syntax in "[Deleting a badly named git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)".

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to do this is to use the  `--`  separator [as seen in the answers by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35681343/674064) [and Lol4t0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35681352/674064) and to put the file name after it.

But using wildcards to avoid the `--…` part of `--exclude`, as [Lasse suggests in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680963/git-remove-files-from-history-which-named-like-a-cli-option#comment59039909_35680963) works indeed, too, as Git seems to do its own wildcard expansion, independent of the shell.

If you were just using it in a single, manual `git rm`, you'd have to either

- escape it:

  ```
  git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch \*exclude
  ```

  or
- quote it

  ```
  git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch '*exclude'
  ```

  or
- delete the actual file first

  ```
  rm ./--exclude
  git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch *exclude
  ```

so that the shell doesn't already perform the expansion and the wildcard is passed to Git at all. But in

```
git filter-branch \
    --index-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch *exclude" HEAD
```

the whole inner command is quoted anyway, and `git filter-branch` doesn't seem to invoke the shell to interpret it, so this works as-is. (Usage with nested commands is probably the reason why Git implements its own wildcard expansion at all.)